# How can I create model form based off the session data in DJango?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Is it possible to create a model form off of the session data in DJango? I am trying to create a shopping cart and within that cart I want the user to be able to update the quantity. I'm thinking I can create my own model and insert the session keys into that model along with my fields but DJango already provides a model so I figure it would be better to use that one. Please help if possible, It's hard to understand sessions as it is (yes I read the documentation).

I want to set a list of products on a page and next to it add a field for quantity that the person chooses to buy. When they click add to cart I'm thinking that it would send over a session id along with the item names and quantities that they chose. From there I will use the item quantity number to create formsets for additional information on each item. Finally, I will send that over to paypal to pay and check out.

Comment: You might need to be a bit clearer. Although sessions are stored in a model, the session data itself is basically a dict so couldn't be used to create a model form. What exactly were you envisaging?

Comment: I edited it to add more information, The reason why I wanted the Model Form was to insert the quantity directly into the session. Is there a way I can find out more about Session dictionaries? Also do you know of a better way to do this?